Launching debugger crashes VS Code dev container
Couple of months back I set up PyTorch in (VS Code) dev container. It worked excellent. It even displayed windows when program was running. Which was unexpected because I didn't set anything up explicitly to allow GUI from docker container. I'm running windows with WSL (Arch) and Docker inside WSL (not Docker Desktop with WSL backend).
Few weeks ago I noticed that if I start debugger (from VS Code) or try to display a window, container crashes. VSC just says "connecting to remote", Docker shows container as stopped. There are no error messages, nothing in the logs (Docker or container).
Except for that everything else works fine. It's using GPU, there are no performance issues, opened ports are visible from Windows (tensorboard).
I'm guessing problem is with some update, because nothing else changed. But I have no idea where to look. I tried googleing but honestly I don't know what to google. I don't know where to look and what to look for. Any help would be appreciated.
Dockerfile:
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.3.1-runtime-ubuntu22.04

# Set environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        git \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
        wget \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        python3-opencv \
        libglib2.0-0

RUN update-ca-certificates

# Upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Non-root user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && mkdir -p /home/$USERNAME/.vscode-server /home/$USERNAME/.vscode-server-insiders \
    && chown ${USER_UID}:${USER_GID} /home/$USERNAME/.vscode-server* \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && usermod -a -G audio,video $USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set user
USER $USERNAME
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME

RUN echo 'alias tensorboard="python3 -m tensorboard.main"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'alias python="python3"' >> ~/.bashrc

devcontainer.json:
{
    "name": "Torch-minigrid",

    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus=all",
        "--ipc=host",
        "--shm-size=512m",
        "--network=host"
    ],
    
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "./Dockerfile"
    },
    
    "forwardPorts": [6006],
    
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
                "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
                    "bash": {
                        "path": "/bin/bash"
                    }
                }
            },
            
            "extensions": [
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "github.copilot",
                "eamodio.gitlens",
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
                "ms-python.isort",
                "christian-kohler.path-intellisense"
            ]
        }
    },
    
    "postCreateCommand": "pip install -r requirements.txt",

    "shutdownAction": "stopContainer"
}


Is it possible to post a minimial example of docker conainer and the configuration of vscode dev container ?

what about VS Code Output Panel? any related-looking messages in any of the output channels there? did you update anything recently?

@starball Console gets stuck. Like it's working but it's taking too long. Lower left corner says reconnecting. Since the last time I saw it working everything was updated. From VS Code all the way to Windows. Only the container image is fixed.
